# Strange comportment of Scanner while reading a keyboard's input at the final line

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

While reading the input of the keyboard with `Scanner(System.in)`, the program stops at the last line of my input, and it continues working only after I press <kbd>enter</kbd> in the input console.

For example, if I want to read this

```
3
f
g
h
```

instead, I get

```
3
f
g

h
```

My program is quite simple,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int count = sc.nextInt();
    sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println("\n"+count);
    while(count>0) {
        System.out.println(sc.nextLine());
        count--;

    }
}
```

I can't understand what is happening. I'll apreciate your help.

Comment: The extra new line you are encountering is most likely **input** and not output. It is because you are missing a new line after you inserted "h", and the application is waiting for a line. It will read it only when it sees it has a \n at the end - the \n you provided.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used the Scanner in a while but I hope this can be useful:

```
String string;
java.util.Scanner mainScanner = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
while( mainScanner.hasNextLine() )
{
    string = mainScanner.nextLine();
    // use string
}
```